# Taking a snapshot of a view including the navigation bar and the tab bar

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uinavigationbar

I'm trying to implement a custom navigation controller transition. After the transition is finished the `fromVC` should be visible behind the `toVC`, so the effect should look like the `toVC` appears on top of the `fromVC`, partly covering it.

So, to achieve the effect I use a snapshot of the `fromView` and inside the `animateTransitioning(using:)` method insert it to the `containerView` as a subview.

```
 snapshot = fromVC.view.snapshotView(afterScreenUpdates: false)
 containerView.addSubview(self.snapshot!)
```

However, the problem is that this snapshot doesn't include the `navigation bar` and the `tab bar`. I've found some answers that suggest to use `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()` but this returns a `UIImage`. I need the snapshot to be a `UIView` to insert it to the `containerView` as a subview. I could use it and create a `UIView` manually with a `UIImageView` and insert it as a subview, but I'm afraid, that's too "heavy" operation for a transition.

If you know how this could be achieved, I would appreciate your help.

Comment: It sounds like you are snapshotting the wrong view. It is not `fromVC` whose view you want to snapshot, but its _parent_ view controller, it seems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will snapshot and unwrap the root view which includes everything except the status bar:

```
guard let snap = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!.snapshotView(afterScreenUpdates: true) else {
    return  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `fromVC` is currently on screen why not do:

```
let snapshot = UIScreen.main.snapshotView(afterScreenUpdates: false)
```

This will take a snapshot of the whole screen wih `navigationBar`, `tabBar` and also `statusBar`

Comment: Yeah, but the problem is the `statusBar` . That would be perfect to take a snapshot without it.

Comment: Check @slickdaddy's answer above